# Is apksigner compliant with JCE (Java Cryptography Extension) specification?

Tags: code-signing, jce, jca, apksigner

Is apksigner tool that comes along with Android SDK Build Tools compliant with JCE (Java Cryptography Extension) specification?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compliant"? apksigner is not a cryptographic extension or provider of crypto primitives. However, it does aim to play nice with JCA/JCE by using crypto primitives via the JCA framework.

Comment: apksigner is a recent addition to apk signing and not sure how mature it is, does the tool works well with providers offered by major HSM vendors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current (as of July 25 2017) `apksigner` version `0.7` released in Andriod SDK Build Tools `26.0.1` supports signing using HSM keys via Sun/Oracle's PKCS #11 Provider and its extensions. For example:

```
apksigner sign --provider-class sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 \
  --provider-arg token.cfg --ks NONE --ks-type PKCS11 app.apk
```

Also see https://geoffreymetais.github.io/code/key-signing/.

Comment: When we use --ks-type PKCS11, we are getting error "java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found". We have the PKCS11 provider configured in java.security file. Any guidance from your end will help.

Comment: Did you also add `--provider-class sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 --provider-arg <your PKCS11 config>`? Also, does the equivalent jarsigner command work for you: `jarsigner -providerClass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 -providerArg <your PKCS11 config> -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 app.apk`

Comment: I get either "jarsigner error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" or 
"jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: load failed" when I change the slot.

Comment: Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: 0x80000067
        at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_Login(Native Method)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.login(SunPKCS11.java:1222)

Comment: It sounds like this issue is not an issue with jarsigner or apksigner, but rather an issue between your HSM and Sun/Oracle's PKCS11 JCA/JCE KeyStore implementation. All I can suggest is consulting the HSM's documentation and/or contacting its manufacturer for more information.